# Add Java FX 2.0 to existing Netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, javafx-2

I have an existing Java project in Netbeans that uses Swing and I would like to start using Java FX 2.0 for some components in that project.
I have dowloaded the latest version of the JDK (1.7.0_03) and enabled JavaFX but when I try adding an `import javafx.xxx` statement, Netbeans can't resolve the link. Do I need to manually add some JARs to my list of external libraries?

Project Properties use "JDK 1.7-FX Enabled":

[image]

which is configured this way:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you created your project in older NetBeans it can miss libraries from FX enabled plaftorm.

You can:

- either recreate the project in NetBeans 7.1+ and copy sources
- or include next library to the libs: `C:/Program Files/Oracle/JavaFX 2.0 SDK/rt/lib/jfxrt.jar`