# Netbeans platform change doesn't take any effects

Tags: java, build, javafx-2, javafx, platform

I have a project with default jdk7 platform, non-including JavaFX.

Now I need to use some classes from javafx.scene.media package, so I've defined a new java platform including JavaFX. Then I go to Project properties > Libraries and edit the platform to the new one. But then, I can, cleand and build, rebuild or whatever, but it doesn't matter. Tried restarting Netbeans but it doesn't work anyway (required packages keep not being found).

However, if I create a new project with my platform, everything goes fine and the packages are found. My question: what more do I need to do to perform the platform change? (please don't ask me to build a brand new project with my platform from the beginning, it's a huge project so I'm trying to avoid that).

Comment: I've had a similar issue and could not find a satisfactory solution in Netbeans 7.1 - see option 2 in the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671597/add-java-fx-2-0-to-existing-netbeans-project Not sure if there is an easier way in 7.2

Comment: Not the formal solution, but solved my problem (and even better than I was going to solve it before, so I don't have to include all javafx stuff). Anyway, it's a huge bug to offer such a functionality when actually it's useless...

Comment: I thought it had been fixed in 7.2 but have not tried.