# Curious about JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-7

I'm very curious about working with JavaFX and standard Java programming in the Netbeans IDE.

If I worked on a standard Java application with the standard GUI interface, and then I decided to apply some JavaFX effects to this application, what type of project would I need to create, or will I have to change my project to javaFX application (since I only decided to use javaFX) ?

What would be the difference if I already had decided I wanted to use JavaFX to my application? Would I create a standard java project and then import the javaFX external packages, or create a JavaFX project?

I'm never sure on what project to create if I decided to use JavaFX.

Thanks much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFx should be fully merged in SE 8 to 9.  I had some troubles with adding jfx to existing projects in the beginning. There is currently no nice way, but the best way to add javafx to an old project is to create a new FX project and [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671597/add-java-fx-2-0-to-existing-netbeans-project).

The difference between a plain java project and an fx project is the template that is used and the dependecies (see above). So the real question is whether you need the skeleton code provided by the template.  I found that it helped initially to get my bearings with FXML, but [Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html) does much of that automagically.

Comment: +1 If you want to work with javafx you should set your project to be a fx project and not the other way around, and the scene builder is great, has saved me a lot of time and its really easy to use

Comment: @MrD I like automagic too :), but I'm a hard core ui junkie so I hesitate to give 'friendly' tools a full endorsement because I often end up fighting against them at some point and ultimately write the code that I want (but only in those cases) - hence 'does _much_ of that...'.  I appreciate the upvote BTW.

Comment: Thanks alot for the replies. Makes alot of sense just to use fx and then to actually apply the effects of the classes/mehtods if you may want them in the future.